# C++ implementing a template that derives from an abstract template

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, abstract, derived

SortedList.h is an abstract template, LinkedSortedList.h derives SortedList.h and is a template, and LinkedSortedList.cpp is a template implementing the functions in LinkedSortedList.h, and is where I'm having problems.

**New New Errors**:  I believe my issue now is I'm not properly overiding the methods in SortedList.h.

Method in SortedList.h:

```
virtual void clear() = 0;
```

Method in LinkedSortedList.h:

```
template <typename Elm> void SortedList<Elm>::clear() override;
```

error:

> error C3240: 'clear' : must be a non-overloaded abstract member function of 'SortedList'

I've tried:

```
void SortedList<Elm>::clear(){}
```

But I still get the same error.  I've tried to find the solution, but have failed.

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of information in the question to what is really needed. Most of what is in this question is useless if you ask me, and will make it harder for people to focus on the real problem at hand. Spending a few minutes reducing the problem to create the question will also help you understanding what the problem might be.

Comment: I took away the LinkedNode.h code, but I still believe you need those 3 files to fully understand what, or how this stuff is being implemented.  Also, more errors I don't know how to handle in the original post.

Comment: You don't need the *whole* contents, for example all functions are somehow equivalent for your problem, are they not? You can leave the three files but present the constructor, maybe a function and hide everything else in ellipses

Comment: @Delliardo In general you should be able to reduce what you are trying to do to a much smaller case.  It's too much to look through for someone who is just "passing by"...   we are in the age of TL;DR.  You ask for people help, you should invest in reducing (as an example - I reported a bug on Friday to an open source project I use, I reduced 1400 lines that caused my crash to 2 lines, yes, it took me an hour but the bug was fixed, committed, & building by sunday night)

Comment: My lack of C++ experience and Visual Studio's lack of underlining errors in .h files kinda didn't help me find where the problem specifically was.  I've now located the problem(s), and have reduced the post.

Comment: Your question has been answered. If you have "new new" questions, accept the answer you have for your original question and post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that you are defining the member of a template:

```
template <typename Elm>
LinkedSortedList<Elm>::LinkedSortedList() {
```

**EDIT**: This is more like multiple questions, but the different error messages:

> c:\users\deltac\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\linked list\linked list\linkedsortedlist.h(23): error C2365: 'LinkedSortedList::size' : redefinition; previous definition was 'member function'

From the code:

```
int size() const;
int size;           // Compiler report here?
```

You cannot use the same identifier to refer to a member variable and a member function. You can reuse the same identifier for different member functions (functions can be overloaded). Rename the member to something else: `int m_size;` for example.

*Error 2* is not an error, but the continuation of the previous error message in the logs (lines that start with *see* don't indicate a new error.

> c:\users\deltac\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\linked list\linked list\main.cpp(27): error C2259: 'LinkedSortedList' : cannot instantiate abstract class

There is at least one pure virtual function in the base (the full error message probably includes the list of them) that has not been overriden. This makes the derived type an abstract type and you cannot instantiate it. Provide the appropriate definitions.

Comment: Thanks for that first one.  Can't believe I did that.  As for overriding the member functions, not sure how to do so, but thanks for helping me pinpoint the error.

Comment: @Delliardo: The problem is not with overloading functions, but with the member variable and the function having the same name. Just rename the member to a different thing, like `int m_size;` (or `int size_` or anything that is **not** `size`)